# SQL Server Export Import Wizard - Display Issue

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-10, ssms, import-from-excel

I have an issue with SQL Server Export Import Wizard display (see attached picture).

[image]

been trying to play around with my machine's display resolution from 1080p to (3200x1800 - recommended), change the scale and layout settings on my windows 10, but no luck. If anyone can help will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on SSMS icon, Properties --> Compatibility --> Select overide high DPI... by Application --> Apply button --> Restart SSMS

Comment: I was about to try your solution, I tried one last time before I did then I found the display was already fixed - even before applying your solution. However, I think this might be a legit solution for display issue. Will accept as an answer.